# Gap in house or foundation

Tags: foundation, house

There is a gap in my house, and it brings up fear that something is wrong.  I haven't asked a local foundation expert yet.  This is normally behind some siding.  Due to some basement flooding, I was removing it, and was surprised to see a gap.  Is it normal for a house to have this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The wall section on the right side looks like concrete, but the left side looks like some type of panelling.  Looks like the gap/space was sealed with some type of foam/caulking.  If two separate sections, then need to know what it look like when new.  To tell if just bad measurements when building or movement.  Having someone there to check the inside and outside will be helpful.

Comment: It does NOT look like foundation crack. It was build that way

Comment: It looks like it may have had a capping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed some trim that was there to cover the end of some type of sheathing.
There does not appear to be any issue to be alarmed about.

I would consider applying some polyester caulk in the opening to insure against water infiltration.  Also examine the area for wood rot and maybe other deterioration, but a foundation issue?  I see no reason for concern in any pic.